# AmCharts.ready is not ready when loaded asynchronously

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amcharts

Initially I put all AmChart configs in AmCharts.ready is everything worked fine.

```
<script src="amcharts/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="amcharts/serial.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    AmCharts.ready(function() {
      console.log("this works");
      /* Other configs */
    })
</script>
```

Somehow it stops working when I introduce RequireJS as instructed in [amCharts meets requireJS](http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/amcharts-meets-requirejs/). Whatever code inside AmChart.ready's callback will not be executed. (Oddly it was executed one time during the debugging)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After a few tests I realized AmChart.ready only pushes the callback into the `onReadyArray` which is later popped for execution after the window.load/onload event. In other words, if AmChart is loaded after window.onload event, AmChart.ready is useless. My workaround is as followed:

```
<script>
    configChart = function() {
      /* Create charts stuff */
    };
    if (AmCharts.isReady) {
      configChart();
    } else {
      AmCharts.ready(configChart);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Still doesn't work in newer versions (version 3.14.1 at this time), but what fixes it is calling the `handleLoad` method manually:

```
AmCharts.handleLoad();
```

Calling it multiple times doesn't seem to do any harm, either.

Answer (score 1):

Because I load in charts asynchronously, I needed to manually set "AmCharts.isReady = true;" before calling my AmCharts functions. For example:

```
var chartData1 = [];
function generateChartData() {
   ...
}

function createStockChart() {
   ...
}

if ($('.amChartDivExists').length > 0) {
    AmCharts.isReady = true;
    generateChartData();
    createStockChart();
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason you posted this as a community wiki? Just curious as it doesn't seem like a community answer since it's essentially a "this is what worked for me" answer.

Comment: @BoltClock Well originally i just made a comment but then I figured that would put a small code snippet to be crystal clear and then I saw "community wiki" and thought why not allow people to edit if they wanted to improve the answer for those having AmCharts async issues.  I should have learned more about "community wiki" before doing that.  I tried to take back community wiki but doesn't seem that i can.